# How to set datagrid MinHeight is datagrid's Resized height in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I want to set DataGrid Minimum height is DataGrid's resized height at runtime. I have tried to set minimum height like this

```
DataGrid.MinHeight = DataGrid.DesireHeight.Height
```

and

```
DataGrid.MinHeight = DataGrid.RenderSize.Height
```

But which could not work when resizing the datagrid at runtime.

[Datagrid resized image at starting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l41Jk.png)

[After resizing i have clicked option button but MinHeight could not maintained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiL3V.png)

Comment: Maybe you have troubles in window markup? Can you show xaml?

Comment: 1. Open some Excel sheet in Excel. 
2.Open find and replace dialog window (ctrl + F)  and type search text in find what comboBox and click FindAll, 
3. Now a datagrid opened at the bottom of find and replace dialog window. which datagrid size increased based on find and replace window resizing. 
4. And then click Option button now note that find and replace window height automatically changed. I need this kind of behavior. If you have any idea please share code snippet.

Comment: Just a guess. Maybe the min height of row prevent this operation? Say the min height of row is 50, and there are 10 rows, and you want the min height of the grid to be 300... So try changing the min height of all the rows first.